# React native function not getting called

Tags: react-native, onpress

Hi I have an a button which should call a function, but when I click on the button nothing seems to happens. I have tried creating 2 desperate buttons to see if functions work individually, which they do. Although do not understand why nothing is happening with the code below

```
          handlePlayAgainClick () {
            dispatch(playAgain())
            goBack('BScreen')
          }
          render() {..
        const { goBack } = this.props.navigation;
      <PlayAgainButtons onPress={ () => this.handlePlayAgainClick}>
```

Comment: can you try this, please? ```<PlayAgainButtons onPress={() => this.handlePlayAgainClick()}>```

Comment: get an error of: cant find variable goBack

Comment: ah got it to work now, need to put that const into the func

Comment: Just a follow up for anyone who visits this...you can also do onPress={this.handlePlayAgainClick}